# How to fix poor performance of Nginx + uwsgi server - break with ~20 requests at a time

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

## Issue

I am using Python-Flask application. Server us unable to handle concurrent request (breaks if 15-20 users uses it at a time).

System Config:
OS: Ubuntu
Proccessor : 2 core
Ram : 4gb
Cloud Provider: AWS

## Configuration

**nginx configuration**

```
worker_processes  1; events {
    worker_connections  1024; }

http { access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log; proxy_connect_timeout 2000; proxy_read_timeout 2000; fastcgi_read_timeout 2000; error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
    include       mime.types;
    gzip on;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name xx.xx.xxx.xx.xx;
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:///home/ubuntu/proj/proj.sock;
            #keepalive_timeout 155s;
        }
    } }
```

**uwsgi.ini file**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = proj.sock
chmod-socket = 665
vacuum = true

worker-reload-mercy = 240 
enable-threads = true
async = 10
ugreen
listen =1000
```

## Question

What might be the reason of such poor performance of server?

Comment: can you tell me the output of `sysctl net.core.somaxconn` ? If it's the default value (128) then it'll be a problem. Also I think since you have 2 cores you need to set 2 worker processes for nginx and uwsgi

Comment: net.core.somaxconn = 1024

Comment: Also we tried with 2 worker, still its same

Comment: You might need `thunder-lock=true` in your uwsgi.ini file too. It's needed for multi-process, multi-threaded configs. Also add `threads=2`.You might also need to check limit for number of open files. If the problem persists you have to use `uwsgitop` and `netstat` to find out which part of your stack is the bottleneck.

Comment: I almost forgot, you need to change `listen 80;` to `listen 80 backlog=2048;` in nginx conf. The default backlog is too low.

Comment: I used the option "threads=2" it gave me the  error "SystemError: you can call uwsgi api function only from the main callable"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188690/discussion-between-saadin-and-ashhar-azeez).